# is INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE quicker than DELETE/INSERT all records

Tags: mysql, t-sql, linked-server

i'm trying to sync up 2 sets of tables, each set is (roughly) identical in structure, one is on a Microsoft SQL Server Database and the other is on a MySQL database, the MSSQL has a Linked Server to the MySQL Database called LNK-SVR

i am wondering which is quicker, Deleting every record in one tables and inserting it back again using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` query or to use a `INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` so that any new records are created and any primary key violations are updated

Comment: Have you timed both methods ?

Comment: @bhs not yet, in the past the DELETE/INSERT all records worked fine, only took a minute for even 100,000+ records however we have started to run tests on the production server (same setup) and it's a hell of a lot slower, since there are a lot of tables that get synced like this and i have other scripts i need to work on to make faster because of the increased time i'm asking this question to see if anyone knows while i work on other scripts (there is like 20 tables which would have different ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE queries)

Comment: Just a note ...but if the source is a live DB there's a good chance your sync errors because of data changes.  For example: `TableA` is copied first,  then `ChildOfTableA`  is copied X second later.  In between, new records are inserted into `TableA` & `ChildOfTableA`.   So when  `ChildofTableA` is copied, it has record that need to FKey to `TableA` and...boom.

Comment: @EBarr there's no worries there, while db is live the tables i am trying to sync are only touched during a scheduled task, only when all the data has been fixed up does it get synced. also, the jobs are run every hour, should we miss some data then in the enxt hour we will get it

Comment: As long as you've though through the issue:-)

Answer (score 0):

In Sql Server 2008 or early you should use a Merge statement to synchonize two tables:

Look at the following sample:
After run it both tables(@sourceTableand @targetTable) have identical rows.

```
DECLARE @sourceTable TABLE(id INT PRIMARY KEY, somefield VARCHAR(255))

DECLARE @targetTable TABLE(id INT PRIMARY KEY, somefield VARCHAR(255))

INSERT INTO @sourceTable (id, somefield) VALUES(1, 'SourceValue1'),
 (3, 'SourceValue3')

INSERT INTO @targetTable (id, somefield) VALUES(1,
 'TargetValue1'), (2, 'TargetValue2')

SELECT * FROM @sourceTable SELECT * FROM @targetTable

MERGE @targetTable AS target USING @sourceTable AS source
ON target.id = source.id
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET somefield = source.somefield
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN   INSERT (id, somefield) VALUES(id, source.somefield)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY source THEN DELETE;

SELECT * FROM @sourceTable
SELECT * FROM @targetTable
```

Comment: while that would work, when i tried it on with one of the tables being a linked server i got an error saying that Merge can be used on remote tables

Comment: You could perform a SELECT INTO to bring the data to the destination server by using a #temporary table or a @Table variable.

Comment: But it depends on the number of records and the performance requeriments.
To synchonize two tables I always try MERGE because I feel very confortable with the syntax and the performance is quite good (in a general basis)

Comment: If you are going to use a temporal table don't forget to index it taking into account the ON clausule on the MERGE statement.